# A vector field dotted with vector <dx , dy> = dr produces an exact differential , what then is an inexact differential?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Lecture says the gradient field with the dot product of the vector dr = < dx, dy> always produces an exact differential.  To me this implies there is such a thing as an inexact differential. What is the intuition between a gradient vector field producing an exact differential vs. any other kind of vector field that my product an inexact differential and what might an inexact differential look like?  I seem to need a geometrical picture to help solidify the difference.

Comment: You might start by reviewing what is meant by an “exact differential.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient of a ("nice") scalar function is related to its total differential
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}
A \cdot dr = \grad \Phi \cdot dr = \sum_i \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_i}  \, dx_i = d\Phi 
$$
so this $A$ (with $A = \grad \Phi$) can be integrated independent of path:
$$
\int\limits_{r_1}^{r_2}A \cdot dr =\int\limits_{r_1}^{r_2}\grad\Phi \cdot dr = \int\limits_{r_1}^{r_2} d\Phi = \phi(r_2)-\phi(r_1)
$$
There are differentials
$$
A \cdot dr = \sum_i A_i dx_i
$$
which can not be expressed as total differential of a potential function, where the integration value depends on the path and not just on the endpoints, where integration along closed paths does not vanish, where $A=(A_i)$ is non-conservative. 
These form inexact differentials.

Theoretical thermodynamics features such differentials prominently.

For ("nice") vector fields in 3D one has the Helmholtz decomposition,
where a vector field can be written as sum of a gradient field and a curl of a vector potential.